# ¿Como debería implementar estos métodos abstractos?

Tags: java

No se como puedo retornar un objeto `GraphicsDevice` si es una clase abstracta, estoy aprendiendo java y esto me tiene un poco perdido, ya que no se muy bien como implementar estos métodos.

```
package Ventana_paquete;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ventanilla {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame prueba = new JFrame(new GraphicsConfiguration() {

        @Override
        public AffineTransform getNormalizingTransform() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public GraphicsDevice getDevice() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public AffineTransform getDefaultTransform() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ColorModel getColorModel(int transparency) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ColorModel getColorModel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Pues mirando así por encima en la Documentacion, la Clase `GraphicsEnvironment`, tiene un método `getDefaultScreenDevice()` que te devuelve un objeto de tipo `GraphicsDevice`. :)

Comment: `GraphicsDevice` extiende de `GraphicsEnvironment` ?

Comment: No. Simplemente tiene un método que te devuelve un objeto de ese tipo. Normalmente en la api de java, cuando miras una clase, te pone que también mires otras que están involucradas. Tendría 'ese metodo' una estructura interna algo así.. `GraphicsDevice elMetodo() {
        return new GraphicsDevice(){
            
        };
    }`

Comment: Muchas gracias , soy bastante nuevo en la API de java..